# unable to access magento front end and backend

Tags: magento

i am using magento 1.9 community edition
suddenly i am not able to access magento front end and magento backend

This is the error page

> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'medpgmagento'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES)
>
> Trace:
>   ../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
>   ../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>   ../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
>   /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>   ../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1202):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(424):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
>   ../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
>   ../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   ../public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   {main}

I have created tmp folder in root and selected cache directory as tmp but still error occurs, i have repaired my sql database in c panel. no use

help me in solving the issue

Comment: It looks as if somehow the username / password combination for your MySQL instance running locally no longer works. Can you try resetting?

Answer (score 0):

Check your username and password for mysql. Then go into your magento file app/etc/local.xml and make sure they match.
Then clear cache folder. This should fix it.